# How to insert the same header and footer on ALL the pages in LaTeX?

Tags: header-footer

I would like to have the same header (with an image) and footer (with contact details) in all pages of the document. With my code it works only with the header. Footer instead appears only on the first page instead. Could someone please help with that?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{noiseimages/}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{marvosym}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 left=20mm,
 top=20mm,
 }
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,      
    urlcolor=blue,
}

%Header
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=.4\textwidth,left]{Logo-WeBBoson-mail}}
\fancyfoot{}
\lfoot{\begin{tabular}{p{2in}}\textsc{We\textcolor{blue}{BB}oson Internet Solutions contattaci: \href{https://webboson.com/}{https://webboson.com}}\\\end{tabular}}
\cfoot{\begin{tabular}{p{2in}}\textsc{\Mobilefone \hspace{1mm} +39 0000000000}\\\end{tabular}}
\rfoot{\begin{tabular}{p{2in}}\textsc{\Letter \hspace{1mm}  info@webboson.com}\\\end{tabular}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}

\begin{document}
    ABC
    \newpage
    ABCD
    \newpage
    ABC
\end{document}
```

Comment: Replace `\lfoot` etc. with the fancy commands `\fancyfoot`.

Comment: Thanks! but it does not work, i have till the same problem, footer appears only on the first page

Comment: I guess that you can have an extra  some `\pagestyle` or `\thispagestyle` somewhere ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that your problem is that in setting up the page geometry you have not allowed for the height of the footer and, as a consequence, it is being printed out of sight off the bottom of the page.

In any case, nice as the [fancyhdr](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) package is, I find that it is easier to "roll your own" headers and footers. What page `\pagetsyle{XXX}` does is execute the command `\ps@XXXX`, or give an error message if no such command exists. So to define your own page style, say `myheader`, you need to define a `\ps@myheader` command. This should define `\@evenfoot`, `\@oddfoot`, `\@evenhead` and `\@oddhead`, which all have the expected meanings. Once this is done, `\pagestyle{myheader}` will "load" your page header settings.

The following MWE does something close to what you want:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{noiseimages/}}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{mwe}
\geometry{
 a4paper, includehead, includefoot,
 total={170mm,257mm},
 headheight=30mm,
 left=20mm,
 }
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    filecolor=magenta,
    urlcolor=blue,
}

%Header
\makeatletter
\def\ps@myheader{
  \ps@empty% for completeness, clear all existing headers
  \def\@oddhead{\includegraphics[height=20mm,left]{example-image}\hfil}
  \let\@evenhead\@oddhead% make right page headers the same as left
  \def\@oddfoot{%
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}llcr@{}}
      \textsc{We\textcolor{blue}{BB}oson Internet}& \textsc{Solutions} \\
      \textsc{Solutions} & \textsc{contattaci} & \textsc{\Mobilefone \hspace{1mm} +39 0000000000}
                             & \textsc{\Letter \hspace{1mm}  info@webboson.com}\\
      \href{https://webboson.com/}{https://webboson.com}
    \end{tabularx}%
  }
  \let\@evenfoot\@oddfoot% make right page footers the same as left
}
\let\ps@plain\ps@myheader% useful as often the first page of a chapter is plain (ams classes use a different style...)
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myheader}
    ABC
    \newpage
    ABCD
    \newpage
    ABC
\end{document}
```

Notice, in particular, that I have added `includehead`, `includefoot` and `headheight=30mm` to the `\geometry` specifications for the page. The manual is a little unclear, so perhaps only one of `includehead` and `includefoot` is needed but it certainly does not hurt, and is clearer, to add of all them.

Here are the first two pages of output:

[image]